# Is there a better way to do substitution guided by a giant lookup table?

Tags: python

I'm trying to substitute the old filenames (that is already uploaded and recognized in a graphic library on one host) to something else (that already exists in the Media Library on another host).

I have a Python script written like so:

```
def imageFilesSub(oldFileName):
    imageDict = {
        'Switzer_Falls_16_140L.jpg': 'Switzer_Falls_140_04232016.jpg', 
        ...
        'Switzer_Falls_16_049L.jpg': 'Switzer_Falls_049_04232016.jpg',
        'Switzer_Falls_09_048L.jpg': 'Switzer_Falls_048_03072009.jpg',
        ...
        'Switzer_Falls_09_013L.jpg': 'Switzer_Falls_013_03072009.jpg',
        'Pasadena_001L.jpg': 'Pasadena_001_04232016.jpg',
        'Switzer_Falls_03_015L.jpg': 'Switzer_Falls_015_02022003.jpg',
        'Tunnel_View_03_010L.jpg': 'Tunnel_View_010_05102003.jpg',
        ...
        }
    newFileName = imageDict[oldFileName]
    return newFileName

blah = imageFilesSub('Switzer_Falls_16_049L.jpg')
print(blah)
```

What would be printed is:

```
'Switzer_Falls_049_04232016.jpg'
```

which is the desired filename.

So the question is this:

Is it possible to perform this substitution without having to make this imageDict containing 42,000 unique keys based on the old filename (as I'd have 42,000 filenames needing to undergo this filename transformation)?

Is there a better way to do this task in general?  Am I going about this problem incorrectly or inefficiently?

Thanks

Comment: If imageDict will not change, I will like to keep it out of the function, or in a closure. If you need to edit it much, then probably a  new class for it.

Comment: Is there any sort of pattern or rule to the replacement names? Or somewhere you can pull the replacement information from? There's gotta be something.

Comment: @DaveQ If I was to make this a class, how do I go about doing it?  I'm not seeing the connection from reading the documentation about classes

Comment: @user2357112   
There is something in that groups of photos that came from a trip or a day. For example, "Switzer_Falls_16_ * L.jpg" => "Switzer_Falls_ * 04232016.jpg" or "Tunnel_View_03_ * L.jpg" => "Tunnel_View_ * _05102003.jpg". But I'm not sure how I could use this given my limited knowledge of Python at this point. If there was a way, then this would condense the list from 42,000 entries to something more like 10,000 entries or less

Comment: @Johnny: Where do you get the date information from? Surely you don't have 42000 picture dates memorized.

Comment: @user2357112  You're right.  I don't have 42k dates memorized, but certain groups of photos have common dates (like if they came from the same trip and/or taken on the same day).  Usually Adobe Bridge provides the dates, but I have old pics that preceded when I used Bridge and had to hand-add them in.  The old filenames came from a string length limit that I had to manually accommodate, which is why the *L.jpg filenames. To match them, I do a search in the WP Media Library and associate the new files with the old file names by hand.  Thus, why I'm looking for a better way to make the imageDict

Answer (score 1):

After building the mapping, keep it in a scope where it is not rebuilt for every lookup.

Also, your method isn't doing anything more than a dictionary lookup, so I'd simplify along the lines of:

```
filename_mapping = {
    'Switzer_Falls_16_140L.jpg': 'Switzer_Falls_140_04232016.jpg', 
    ...
}

for filename in filenames:
    try:
        do_something(filename_mapping[filename])
    except KeyError:
        # handle scenario where there is no mapping
        pass
```

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to brute force the population of the file mapping, but it's looking more and more like it's not likely to find a more compressed or efficient way of doing this.  Thanks for the flag of the KeyError though